# How to control character enocding in forms so french accents are properly stored

Tags: mysql, csv, character-encoding, photoshop

I have a web form that for entering names.  Sometimes, the names contain french characters.  I am having a problem with, in particular, the `é`.

When the data is viewed and retrieved, it appears as it should, however, when the CSV is exported and opened in Open Office using UTF-8 encoding, the french character will translate to `É` or sometimes even `È` which is completely wrong.

But it's not consistent, it seems that the character will change depending on the method used to input the character (using the `ALT+###` to enter, versus copy/paste from something).

How do I make the user input consistent so that the output always works?

The end use is a CSV file that Photoshop uses to populate field variables.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure which platform you are on, but it may be that your CSV export is valid utf-8 that is being read as latin-1, or the other way around.

Comment: Mac OS X, can I do anything about that? When I read the file using UTF-8 in Open Office, I get the diamond question mark.

Comment: On my own MacBook, everything is in UTF-8. Are you sure that you're not storing utf-8 data in a swedish/latin collated column?

Comment: The columns appear to be utf8_unicode_ci; perhaps it's the query I use to build the csv.